# Random fill colour for shapes in Python(TKinter)

Tags: python, list, random, tkinter

I am wondering how to get a random color out of a list to use in the `draw_rectangle()`

```
colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet"]

canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 60, self.y + 60, fill = random.choice(colors))
```

This causes my code to crash, what else can I try?

Comment: are you importing random? import random

Comment: Please be more specific. How does it crash? What error is shown?

Answer (score 5):

```
de=("%02x"%random.randint(0,255))
re=("%02x"%random.randint(0,255))
we=("%02x"%random.randint(0,255))
ge="#"
color=ge+de+re+we
```

and in tkinter  put

```
fill=color
```

easy
you can also make

```
fill="#"+("%06x"%random.randint(0,16777215))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) like this

```
import random
colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"]
canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, self.x + 60, self.y + 60, fill = random.choice(colors))
```

This will pass a random color to `fill` whenever this code is executed.

Comment: my TK window crashes when I try this

Comment: Try to store the result of `random.choice(color)` in a variable and print it.

Answer (score 0):

Also I do this way:

```
color = f'#{random.randrange(256**3):06x}'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use choice, from package [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

```
random.choice(color)
```